# Multiple javascript apps on Pepper robot and ALMemory data retrieval

Tags: javascript, pepper

I have designed several javascript applications and would like to know how to run them using Choregraphe. I can succesfully run one application at a time, but don't know how to run different apps in one Chographe behavior. For example, I need the user to input some data using the tablet at a specific point of the behavior, and after performing some animation, I need the user to select a button on the tablet (another app). How would this be possible?

Secondly, I have managed to write data to ALMemory from within the javascript script, but can't retrieve ALMemory data using getData. Could anybody help me with this? I have tried this, but with no success https://community.ald.softbankrobotics.com/en/forum/get-data-almemory-javascript-11761

Answer (score 1):

To run different javascript scripts, you should probably either embed them into different html pages, and load them from Choregraphe using @ALTabletService.loadUrl@.

For getData, remember that it's using futures, so you will have to write something like :

```
session.service("ALMemory").then( function(almemory) {
    almemory.getData("myKey").then( function( myKey ) {
        # do something with myKey #
    })
})
```